# How use culture in WCF which is set by user in codebehind of ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, cultureinfo, culture

how is possible change culture info in asp.net web forms code behind and next get this value in wcf?

In code behind I'm using this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pl-PL");
```

And for getting value in wcf this:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```

But always return "en-US" and not pl ... Thanks for answers

Comment: And this is about javascript because... ?

Comment: what do you mean with javascript?

Comment: Why would changing it in one application (or even thread) update another... it doesn't, You need a shared config store of some sort (database, common file, etc.)

Comment: It's possible if you pass the culture info to the service. The WCF service is running in its own context and culture, so CurrentInfo will return the WCF culture not the client.

Comment: So, is possible do it without JS? I need work with that culture which is set by user in WCF.

Comment: I'm sorry ... now i saw my wrong title :)